# ¿Cómo inicializar un ArrayList y poder utilizar el mismo arreglo en otras clases?

Tags: java, array, poo, arraylist, constructor

estoy haciendo un proyecto en Java donde el usuario inserta algunos datos y los guarda en un arreglo de objetos. Me di cuenta que el ArrayList se instanciaba cada vez que quería guardar un nuevo usuario, así que me gustaría saber dónde puedo inicializar este ArrayList y cómo obtener un valor del arreglo para poder imprimir la información que contiene el arreglo.

Clase 1

```
public class Alumno_ {
// Variables que se utilizarán. De mayor importancia.
public int mat_alu;
String app_alu;
String apm_alu;
String nom_alu;
String carr_alu;
String gen_alu;

// Constructor
public Alumno_(int mat_alu, String app_alu, String apm_alu, String nom_alu, String carr_alu, String gen_alu) {
    this.mat_alu = mat_alu;
    this.app_alu = app_alu;
    this.apm_alu = apm_alu;
    this.nom_alu = nom_alu;
    this.carr_alu = carr_alu;
    this.gen_alu = gen_alu;
}
}
```

Clase 2

```
public class RegistroAlumno extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
JTextField mat, app, apm, nom, carr, gen;
JButton guardar, modificar;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    RegistroAlumno in = new RegistroAlumno();
    in.crearGUI();
    in.setSize(830, 200);
    in.setVisible(true);
}

private void crearGUI() {
    JLabel mat_, app_, apm_, nom_, carr_, gen_;
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container frame = getContentPane();
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    // Etiquetas
    mat_ = new JLabel("Matrícula:");
    app_ = new JLabel("Apellido Paterno:");
    apm_ = new JLabel("Apellido Materno:");
    nom_ = new JLabel("Nombre(s):");
    carr_ = new JLabel("Carrera:");
    gen_ = new JLabel("Género:");
    // Campos de texto
    mat = new JTextField(10);
    app = new JTextField(15);
    apm = new JTextField(15);
    nom = new JTextField(15);
    carr = new JTextField(10);
    gen = new JTextField(10);
    // Botones
    guardar = new JButton("Guardar");
    modificar = new JButton("Modificar");
    // ActionListener
    guardar.addActionListener(this);
    modificar.addActionListener(this);
    // Se agregan los objetos de acuerdo al orden en como queremos que se ordenen
    frame.add(mat_);
    frame.add(mat);
    frame.add(app_);
    frame.add(app);
    frame.add(apm_);
    frame.add(apm);
    frame.add(nom_);
    frame.add(nom);
    frame.add(carr_);
    frame.add(carr);
    frame.add(gen_);
    frame.add(gen);
    frame.add(guardar);
    frame.add(modificar);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(e.getSource() == guardar) {
        capturar();
    } else if(e.getSource() == modificar) {
        /*¿Cómo mando el arrayList? */
    }
}

private void capturar() {
/* Se crea de nuevo el array */
    ArrayList<Alumno_> salon = new ArrayList<Alumno_>();
    int matricula = Integer.parseInt(mat.getText());
    String paterno = app.getText();
    String materno = apm.getText();
    String nombre = nom.getText();
    String carrera = carr.getText();
    String genero = gen.getText();
    Alumno_ alum = new Alumno_(matricula, paterno, materno, nombre, carrera, genero);
    sal.add(alum);
    //imprimir(sal);
}
```

Clase 3

```
public Imprimir(){
/* ¿Cómo se obtiene el array y método para imprimir? */
}
```

Comment: Olvidé mencionar que se está haciendo en una interfaz gráfica y es por eso que en la opción de registrar nuevo usuario se manda a llamar una clase con el formulario y aquí es en donde tenía la inicialización del arreglo.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: @NicolasOñate agregué un código como ejemplo, este no es mi proyecto, pero al resolver este me ayudaría muchísimo para mi proyecto. Espero y me puedas ayudar a solucionar el problema.

Comment: Si un Objeto lo creas en un método solo va a estar disponible para ese método. Si lo creas en una clases solo podra ser accesible desde otra clase si lo expones con un get o similar o lo haces public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Me di cuenta que el ArrayList se instanciaba cada vez que quería
>   guardar un nuevo usuario

No tienes que crear nuevamente el array `salon`, simplemente crealo una vez y en el método `capturar()` se agregara un objeto `Alumno_` cada vez que este sea llamado:

```
ArrayList<Alumno_> salon = new ArrayList<Alumno_>();

private void capturar() {       
    int matricula = Integer.parseInt(mat.getText());
    String paterno = app.getText();
    String materno = apm.getText();
    String nombre = nom.getText();
    String carrera = carr.getText();
    String genero = gen.getText();
    Alumno_ alum = new Alumno_(matricula, paterno, materno, nombre, carrera, genero);
    sal.add(alum);
    //imprimir(sal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mueve la lista (ArrayList salon = new ArrayList();) fuera del método, así lo tendrás accesible a todos los métodos de la clase.

Comment: Una duda, tengo que hacer uso de settersy getters?

Comment: Si solo lo vas a usar a nivel de esta clase no es necesario. Tendrías que hacerlo si fueras a usarlo en otras clases distintas a ésta, pero de momento no es tu caso.